# Point of discontinuity of complex function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Show that $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(z)=$

\begin{cases}
\frac{z^2}{|z|^2}  &, z\ne 0 \\[2ex]
1 &, z=0
\end{cases}
is continuous for all $z_0\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ but not in $z_0=0$

My thought here was that for the $z\ne0$ the function is continous as a product and composition of continous functions. To show that the function is not continous in $z=0$ i first wanted to rewrite the function as
$\frac{z^2}{|z|^2} = \frac{z^2}{z\overline{z}} = \frac{z}{\bar{z}}$ ,where $\bar z$ is the conjugate and show that with a  sequence $z_n\in\mathbb{C}, \lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=0$ we would see that $lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n) \ne 1=f(0)$ . My issue though is that i am stuck at $lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{z_n}{\overline{z_n}}$ and i don't really know how the conjugate effects the series or what would be a better approach.

Comment: Hint: what is the relation between  $arg(z^2)$ and $arg(z)$?

Comment: @FOE i guess the $\arg(z^2)=2\arg(z)$ because of $z*z = |z|^2*e^{i(\varphi+\varphi)}$. I don't see the connection though.

Comment: Choose two different numbers such that $2arg(z) \neq 2arg(w)$ and define the sequences $\frac{z}{n}, \frac{w}{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this $(z \neq 0)$:
$$
f(z)-f(0) = \frac{z^2}{\lvert z \rvert^2} - 1 = \frac{z^2-\lvert z \rvert^2}{\lvert z \rvert^2}
$$
Then take the sequence $z_n := \frac{i}{n}$ that clearly converges to $0$. So:
$$
\frac{z_n^2-\lvert z_n \rvert^2}{\lvert z_n \rvert^2} = \frac{-\frac{2}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = -2
$$
Does $-2$ converge to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ was continuous at $0$, then its restriction to $\Bbb R i$ (the set of purely imaginary complex numbers) would also be continuous at $0$. But$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):f(xi)=\begin{cases}-1&\text{ if }x\ne0\\1&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$